# How do I convert Timestamp (having milliseconds) to EPOCH in Redshift

Tags: sql, date, timestamp, amazon-redshift, epoch

How do I convert from timestamp (having milliseconds) to epoch

For E.g.,

```
Timestamp1 - 2019-10-20 11:43:47.298
Timestamp2 - 2019-10-20 11:43:47.469
```

Using EPOCH gives the same results for both the timestamps, even though they are different timestamps (different milliseconds)

Query-

```
extract('epoch' from timestamp '2019-10-20 11:43:47.298')::bigint * 1000
extract('epoch' from timestamp '2019-10-20 11:43:47.469')::bigint * 1000

Result - 1571571827000
```

I want different results as they have separate timestamps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't cast to `bigint` if you don't want to lose the millisecond precision:

```
select
    extract('epoch' from timestamp '2019-10-20 11:43:47.298') * 1000 epoch1,
    extract('epoch' from timestamp '2019-10-20 11:43:47.469') * 1000 epoch2
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=87b3a60834651af9bd663dc04d92b6a4)**:

```
epoch1        | epoch2       
:------------ | :------------
1571571827298 | 1571571827469
```